# WPF Prism Binding in HamburgerMenu via regions doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mahapps.metro, hamburger-menu

I have a WPF Application in net core. I use prism and mahapps.
In MainWindow I have a Hamburger menu where I add HamburgerMenuGlyphItem via regions.
In VM for HamburgerMenuGlyphItemView, I set a label property but it doesn't work. The label property doesn't update on MenuItemControl. When I check the DataContext for the DeclarationMenuItemView in LiveVisualTree it says "DeclarationMenuItemView" not the ViewModel...

Here is the MainWindow with DataTemplate For HamburgerMenuItem

```
    <mah:MetroWindow x:Class="PrismJPKEditor.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/" 
        xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
                  xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:PrismJPKEditor.Modules.JPK.ViewModels;assembly=PrismJPKEditor.Modules.JPK"
        xmlns:core="clr-namespace:PrismJPKEditor.Core;assembly=PrismJPKEditor.Core"
        Title="{Binding Title}" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <DockPanel>

        <DockPanel.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MenuItemViewModel}">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid"
                      Height="48"
                      Background="Transparent">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type mah:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=CompactPaneLength}" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentControl Grid.Column="0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Content="{Binding Icon}"
                                    Focusable="False" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               FontSize="16"
                               Text="{Binding Label}"/>
            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type mah:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=IsPaneOpen}" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="RootGrid" Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
        </DockPanel.Resources>

        <Menu  DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="Plik">
                <MenuItem Header="Otwórz"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Zapisz"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Zapisz jako"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Zamknij"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <mah:HamburgerMenu DockPanel.Dock="Left"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"   OptionsItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}">
            <mah:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
                <mah:HamburgerMenuItemCollection prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static core:RegionNames.HamburgerMenuRegion}"/>
            </mah:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
        </mah:HamburgerMenu>

        <!--<mah:HamburgerMenu DockPanel.Dock="Left"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static core:RegionNames.HamburgerMenuRegion}">
            
        </mah:HamburgerMenu>-->

        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static core:RegionNames.ContentRegion}"/>

    </DockPanel>
</mah:MetroWindow>
```

Here is the MenuItemViewModel from MenuItemTemplate

```
public class MenuItemViewModel : BindableBase, IHamburgerMenuItemBase
{
    private object _icon;
    private object _label;
    private object _toolTip;
    private bool _isVisible = true;

    public object Icon
    {
        get => _icon;
        set => SetProperty(ref _icon, value);
    }

    public object Label
    {
        get => _label;
        set => SetProperty(ref _label, value);
    }

    public object ToolTip
    {
        get => _toolTip;
        set => SetProperty(ref _toolTip, value);
    }

    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get => _isVisible;
        set => SetProperty(ref _isVisible, value);
    }
}
```

And here is the ViewModel for MenuItemView when I initialize the Label property which should be working

```
 public class DeclarationMenuItemViewModel : MenuItemViewModel
{

    public DeclarationMenuItemViewModel()
    {
        Label = "Deklaracja";
        
    }
    
}
```

And here is the MenuItemView

```
  <mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem x:Class="PrismJPKEditor.Modules.JPK.HamburgerMenuItems.DeclarationMenuItemView"
              xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrismJPKEditor.Modules.JPK.HamburgerMenuItems"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
                            prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"   
                          
                            >
    
    

</mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>
```

Here is the Region adapter for the HamburgermenuItemCollection

```
public HamburgerMenuItemCollectionRegionAdapter(IRegionBehaviorFactory regionBehaviorFactory) : base(regionBehaviorFactory)
    {

    }

    protected override void Adapt(IRegion region, HamburgerMenuItemCollection regionTarget)
    {
        region.Views.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                foreach (HamburgerMenuGlyphItem element in e.NewItems)
                {
                    regionTarget.Add(element);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    protected override IRegion CreateRegion()
    {
        return new SingleActiveRegion();
    }
}
```

Because the View DeclarationMenuItemView isn't in the Views folder, I have set

```
 public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<DeclarationMenuItemView, DeclarationMenuItemViewModel>();

    }
```

Here is the Module class

```
  public class JPKModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public JPKModule(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {            
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.HamburgerMenuRegion, typeof(HamburgerMenuItems.DeclarationMenuItemView));
        //_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.HamburgerMenuRegion, typeof(HamburgerMenuItems.SellMenuItem));
        //_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.HamburgerMenuRegion, typeof(HamburgerMenuItems.BuyMenuItem));
        //_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.HamburgerMenuRegion, typeof(TestView));

    }

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<DeclarationMenuItemView, DeclarationMenuItemViewModel>();

    }
}
```

For some testing I changed the DataTemplate to

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HamburgerMenuItem" DataType="{x:Type mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem}">
        <DockPanel Height="48" LastChildFill="True">
            <Grid x:Name="IconPart"
          Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type mah:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=CompactPaneLength}"
          DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                <Image Margin="12"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Source="{Binding Glyph}" />
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextPart"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="16"
               Text="{Binding Label}" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type mah:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=PanePlacement}" Value="Right">
                <Setter TargetName="IconPart" Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Right" />
                <Setter TargetName="TextPart" Property="Margin" Value="8 0 0 0" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And in the cs file of the View I set

```
public partial class DeclarationMenuItem : HamburgerMenuGlyphItem
{
    



    public DeclarationMenuItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Glyph = "M";
        Label = "Test";
    }
}
```

And from here Label is working ..

And when I add to the xaml file of the view the line

```
 Label = "{Binding Label"}
```

I get following error:

Error   1   MainWindowViewModel Label   DeclarationMenuItemView.Label   String  Label property not found on object of type MainWindowViewModel.

But VM for DeclarationMenuItem is   DeclarationMenuItemViewModel not the
MainWindowViewModel

Comment: You cannot just put Region to any control, mah:HamburgerMenuItemCollection  is just a collection type. ContentControl, Selector, and ItemsControl are the supported one, you need to create a RegionAdapter for other controls that are not inherited from these.

Comment: @AthulRaj I have region adapter, I will update a post in a minute

Comment: Did you register the region adapter ? does a break point hit in adapt method ?

Comment: @AthulRaj Yes, debug hits the adapt method. Application is working without exceptions. I can see in HamburgerMenu my new item but the Label property is null

Comment: where are you registering the views to core:RegionNames.HamburgerMenuRegion

Comment: @AthulRaj In my only one "JPKModule" I will add the code in a few seconds.

Comment: In region adapter you are adding HamburgerMenuGlyphItem , but you added ItemTemplate based on viewmodel, that maybe the reason. Do you really need that item template ? according to the documentation here https://mahapps.com/docs/controls/HamburgerMenu, it's already expecting a HamburgerMenuGlyphItem

Comment: @AthulRaj without the item template I got the class name on the MenuItemBar.

Comment: https://mahapps.com/docs/controls/HamburgerMenu try using the datatemplated used in this example

Comment: @AthulRaj which one? Because I have tried with dataType .. GlyphItem and it didn’t work too –

Comment: @AthulRaj okay I researched that HamburgerMenuGlyphItem  doesn't have a DataContext